# LoadHtml() messes up MathJax syntax

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to load a page with the following code:

```
<p>Generally for $n$ events $A_1, A_2,\cdots,A_n$, we have</p><br>

$P\biggl(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr) =\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)-\sum_{i < j}P(A_i\cap A_j) $
$ \hspace{32pt} +\sum_{i < j < k}P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)-\ \cdots\ +(-1)^{n-1}\, P\biggl(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr)$

<hr />
```

However, after using `doc.LoadHtml(html)`, the `InnerHtml` is now:

```
<p>Generally for $n$ events $A_1, A_2,\cdots,A_n$, we have</p><br />

$P\biggl(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr) =\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)-\sum_{i < j}p(a_i\cap="" a_j)="" $="" 
$="" \hspace{32pt}="" +\sum_{i="" />< j="" />< k}p(a_i\cap="" a_j\cap="" a_k)-\="" \cdots\="" +(-1)^{n-1}\,="" p\biggl(\bigcap_{i="1}^n" a_i\biggr)$="" /><hr />
```

I've tried using the following:

- `htmlDoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;`
- `htmlDoc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;`
- `htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax = false;`
- `htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;`

with no luck.

Comment: [You probably want to add the code you're using that gives you that result because a simple test on .Net Fiddle does not cause me the above mentioned issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMyDXx)

Comment: You are right. I tried it out on .Net Fiddle myself, and the problem dissappeared. It seems they changed something around version 1.4.9, since the problem appears again, if choosing this version, when adding the Nuget package. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my `HtmlAgilityPack` to version `1.8.9`, and the problem disappeared.